# Clarifying the use of a window controller

Tags: macos, cocoa, model-view-controller, nsdocument, nswindowcontroller

I've been learning about when to use WindowController and when to put stuff in the Document object. Looks like Document can work fine as a Controller if you have a simple interface. I have a simple interface in my application, but is it a good practice to put IB outlets into WC anyway? What would be a scenario when you would NOT want to use a WC?

Comment: I generally keep everything in the document and avoid custom window controllers as long as there is only one window per document.

Comment: thanks, @ughoavgfhw . How do you refer to a current window from within NSDocument? Would you use `[[[self windowControllers]objectAtIndex:0]window]` instead of `self`?

Comment: That would work, but it is generally better to use `[self windowForSheet]`. It is easier to write and, if you use multiple windows in the future, it will automatically select the frontmost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some scenarios:

1. A document object you intend to use with multiple windows (as commenter noted above) or having different views
2. A document object you could potentially open and process without displaying a window at all
3. An application with so much controller code that it's difficult to manage with a single class

During window initialization, the the document will instantiate the window controller.

After that happens, part of the point of separating the model controller and view controller is *removing the document's dependency on the window*.

As you refine your design, take a look at places where the document needs access to the window, and consider whether you can implement that functionality a different way, for example, by handling it in the window controller instead of the document.